# `partial` with mutable default parameters

Tags: python

So I meet a problem while using `partial` with multi-processing pool. And the following is a minimal, re-producable code piece.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.copy()


def change(i, x):
    x[i] = 0

# method 1
for i in range(3):
    change(i, a)
print(a)
# Output: [0, 0, 0]

# method 2
with Pool(2) as pool:
    pool.map(partial(change, x=b), list(range(3)))
print(b)
# Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

See the later method doesn't change the passed list. I guess this somehow can be explained by `function is the level-1 object in python`, but don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: `multiprocessing` does copy of arguments for each process, so your original list `b` won't be changed, if you need shared mutable state -- use `threading` instead or some sort of database

Comment: Ooops. So it's a multi-processing problem. Thanks.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: `multiprocessing` does of course define some sharable mutable data structures if you do need the GIL freedom (and contention for the shared state isn’t very strong).